# Prime pairs ($p$, $q$) such that $p|q^m - 1$ for some integer $m$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $p$ and $q$ be two different prime numbers. Is it true that there exist an integer $m$ such that $p | q^m - 1$?

If no, what family of prime pairs are known to have the above property?

Comment: Fermat's little theorem tells you there's always such an integer $m=p-1.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exists such a power $m$ for all primes $p$ and $q$.  (In fact, we can relax this to relatively prime pairs of numbers -- the argument below still goes through.)

Consider the powers of $q$ modulo $p$.  These form a subgroup of the multiplicative group of the integers modulo $p$, this latter typically denoted $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}^\times$.  Since the powers of $q$ form a subgroup, at least one such power is congruent to $1$ modulo $p$.  (Subgroups must contain the identity of the containing group.)  Let one of those powers be $m$, so that $q^m \cong 1 \mod p$.  But then $p|q^m-1$ and we are done.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}
\frac17 &= 0.142857142857142857\dots
\\ \frac{10^6}7 - \frac17 &= 142857.142857142857\dots - 0.142857142857\dots
\\ \frac{10^6 - 1}{7} &= 142857
\\ 10^6 - 1 &= 142857 \cdot 7
\end{align}$$.

Likewise all primes $p$ other than $2$ and $5$ have infinite decimal representations for $\frac1p$ in base $10$.  You can use this repeating representation to discover an $n$ and $k$ such that $10^n - 1 = p\cdot k$.  So for any prime p, there exists a value of $n$ such that $p$ divides $10^n - 1$.

You can likewise use the repeating digit representation of $\frac{1}{p}$ in base $q$ to derive $n$ and $k$ such that $q^n - 1 = k\cdot p$.